# How to put the characters from a File in to a char string?

Tags: c, readfile, file-copying

So here is my attempt at it but I'm getting a few errors which I don't know how to fix. 
17.2 Warning : passing argument 2 of putc makes pointer from integer without a cast.
C:\mingw ....... note expected Struct FILE* but' but argument is of type int.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main (void) {
FILE *fp;
int c;
char copywords;

fp = fopen("gues20.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
exit(1);

c = getc(fp);
while(c != EOF)
{
putc(c, copywords);
c = getc(fp);
}
printf("%d", copywords);
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putc/

Comment: If you really want to put the characters in a string, then the `fputc()` is way off. Is the title wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second argument to **[putc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fputc.3.html)** is a file stream. But you pass a plain charcter. Use:

```
while(c != EOF)
{
putc(c, stdout);
c = getc(fp);
}
```

to print in stdout.

Comment: this is obviously an assignment, why not point him to relevant documentation rather than flat out code it for him? ...

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc Nothing much to hide really in a trivial case like this. I have pointed out the problem and given a link to manual. If OP doesn't want to learn, it's his/her choice.

Comment: Thanks KingsIndian. No reference to stdout in my notes so there was no way for me to know it existed and could solve my problems!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
putc(c, copywords);
```

is wrong. First, `copywords` is never initialized or used above this line, so it's obviously wrong to reference it. Second, the prototype of `putc()` is:

```
int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
```

which explains your compiler warning.